# Delphi XE6 slow ISAPI connection

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, isapi

So we have this ISAPI application with server has DSHTTPWebDispatcher,DSServer & DSServer . We are using datasnap for connection between client and server. At client we are using DSRestConnection, sqlConnection etc.

Problem is that it takes about 6 to 7 seconds just for request to reach from client to Server. Any suggestion what can be done to improve this speed.

Thank You.

Comment: Which two points are you observing on each end where you've measured 6 to 7 seconds? How does it perform when both Client and Server are on the same machine?

Comment: Thanks Jerry for reply. I record time when I sent EchoString message from client. I also record time at server where EchoString is defined and record time at start of function. This is how I know how much time it took. I am in process of working on same machine. Right now its on different machine. Will update soon.

Comment: So looks like local machine is instant. What do you think is going on.

Comment: The bottleneck has to be somewhere in your network then. Are you connecting by IP Address or by Host Name? If the latter, then try by IP Address so it doesn't have to do a DNS lookup. Besides that, your problem is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow, and you'll likely have to seek networking help elsewhere: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I am connecting using hostname. I will look into your suggestion.